# How to turn off network using Windows 7 Task Manager?

Tags: windows-7, networking, scheduled-tasks

I've looked online and on this website about how to schedule things and about networks, but I haven't found anything that would help me figure how to do schedule networks. I've seen task manager can turn off/hibernate/sleep the laptop at a specific time and i was wondering if it can do the same for the network.

More specifically I'm asking how do I turn off all networks at a specific time (and optionally turning them back on also at a specific time.)
I asked about Task Manager but if there are other methods I'm open to checking them out.

OS is Windows 7.

Comment: You might mean Task Scheduler instead of Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You might enable or disable it with the follow commands. Trying to create two batch-files enable/disable, and use the task-scheduler to set a time.

Use another name if not local area.

> netsh interface show interface
>
> netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled
>
> netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=enabled

Or you might use this.

> Start elevated Command Prompt.
>
> Get NIC list and index number:
> wmic nic get name, index
>
> Enable NIC with index number: (e.g.: 7)
> wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable
>
> Disable NIC with index number: (e.g.: 7)
> wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable